# Bad performance when I insert into variable table instead of temp table

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

The following returns only 3 records and takes less than second:-

```
SELECT * FROM SomeView Where X='1233'
```

The following takes half minute:-

```
INSERT INTO @T111
   SELECT * FROM SomeView Where X='1233'
```

It is less than one second if I used temp tables instead:-

```
SELECT * INTO #TTT FROM SomeView Where X='1233'
```

Explanation please :)